# How to create fake sound card on Linux server

Tags: linux, flash

I'm running Firefox with Xvfb on a Linux server (CentOS 5.4). I alspo have the Flash plugin loaded, but it does not work because I do not have a sound card:
$ alsamixer
alsamixer: function snd_ctl_open failed for default: No such file or directory

It is possible to create a fake sound card on the server?

Comment: Why do you need to view Flash on a server? Why do you even have a GUI on a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be as easy as enabling *snd-dummy* kernel module, which fakes a sound card.

Try `modprobe snd-dummy` and if that helps, you might want to add snd-dummy to your */etc/modules.conf* or wherever CentOS wants default modules added; might also be under */etc/modprobe.d*.